# Blank web application project added to an existing solution does not compile

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I want to create a new ASP.NET Core project in an existing solution (in Visual Studio 2015). But even a blank project just created from a template does not compile because it cannot find some referenced libraries (at least, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging). It seems that some solution-global settings affect looking for these packages because, when I create a new solution, everything is OK. What can these settings be?

What I know:

1. The source code editor shows namespaces Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as unused (grey), and classes and methods defined in these extensions as unavailable.
2. The References list in the solution explorer show the names of the missing libraries, but does not have an expanding list under them. For other packages, there is a list containing dependencies and the dll file, but not for these ones.
3. The project added to the existing solution looks for packages in \Users\%USERNAME%\.dnx\packages, whilst the project in a separate solution looks for packages in \Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages (according to the Path property in Properties window). But the missing libraries exist in both these directories.
4. Among project dependencies, the missing libraries are the ones that are compiled for older .NET versions. For example, the folder with package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json in the package cache contains versions targeted for net451 and netstandard1.3, and this package is available. But the folder with package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration targets only netstandard1.1, and the project behaves as if this package did not exist at all. The same situation is with other packages -- when the package cache targets netstandard1.3 or netstandard1.6, everything is OK, but the packages compiled for netstandard1.0 or netstandard1.1 are unavailable. Again, in a separate solution, packages in the package cache are the same, but the compiler sees all these libraries independently on their targets.
5. `dotnet restore` brings the project into a strange state -- almost all references in the solution explorer are shown as broken, the source code editor does not complain about classes defined in  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but it requires to add dependency to System.Runtime 4.0.0.0. The project still does not compile. Restoring packages from Visual Studio returns the project to the state described above.
6. I have tried templates "Empty", "Web API", and "Web Application" in groups "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" and "ASP.NET Core WebApplication (.NET Framework)". The result is the same with all six.
7. Changing the target framework in project.json (I have tried net451, net452, net46, net462) does not help either.

What can be the reason of such behaviour, or what else should I check?

VS2015 Update 3, .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS2015 Tooling Preview 2, and .NET Framework 4.6.2 are installed.

Comment: you need to install vs2015 update 3 then get the latest asp.net from http://dot.net currently you are using very old preview versions, dnx is no longer a thing, it was a thing in the betas and early rcs

Comment: VS2015 Update 3, .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS2015 Tooling Preview 2 (the latest that I see on dot.net), and .NET Framework 4.6.2 are installed. Thank you for the information about dnx, I will remove references to it from my question. I tried it just because I found its mentions in other answers. Anyway, with all net4X targets the project do not work either.

Comment: Does your solution use previous versions of ASP.NET Core (Rc1 or earlier)? What is in your global.json?

Comment: have you tried control-shift right click and choose open command window here on the solution folder, then run the command dotnet restore --no-cache

Comment: Tseng, Joe, the combination of your answers helped! I removed global.json (it really pointed to beta SDK, and that was all that it contained) AND restored packages with --no-cache option, after a couple of recompilation attempts the project came into order. Could you please make it an answer instead of a comment so that I could accept it?